# Jagged arrays, populating them from a List<string>

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, jagged-arrays

User enters a series of values into textboxes:

```
Textbox 1: 10,9,8,7

Textbox 2: 1,2,3,4
```

Id then like to sort these two string and populate a `List<string>`. Once sorted (already figured out how to do that part), id like to create a jagged array of the inputs like so:

```
string[][] Arr = new string[2][];

Arr[0] = new string[] { "10", "9", "8", "7" };
Arr[1] = .....
```

but instead of manually typing in the values, id like to use the `List<string>` mentioned above.

Is this possible (thus far, my attempts have failed rather miserably)? If not, could someone suggest a possible alternative approach?

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: Based on the answers, I got it working. Sorry again for not making it clear what I meant by sort.

```
List<string> tempString = new List<string>();
tempString.Add("10,9,8,7");
tempString.Add("1,2,3");

string[][] Arr = new string[2][];

for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
{
    string[] values = tempString[x].Split(',').ToArray();

    Arr[x] = values;
}
```

Comment: TextBox.GetValue() and String.Split?

Comment: I don't get your question. Which part causes your problems? The parsing of the user entered strings?

Comment: So you want to create a `List<string>` for each textbox, and then convert each to an array of `string` and then add it to your jagged array?  I don't see the point of having the `List<string>` then -- just parse the string as an array and then add it to your jagged array.  But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want the user to enter comma-separated values into 2 textboxes, then combine and sort into a single list? Not sure where the jagged array comes in...

Comment: I wanted to have the list<string> so that i can determine which textbox is number 1, which is number 2 etc. The order of the strings "10,9,8,7" = 1st and "1,2,3,4" = 2nd is important but not the actual order of whats in them.Sorry for not making that particularly clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create lists from the strings:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>(textbox1.Text.Split(','));
List<string> list2 = new List<string>(textbox2.Text.Split(','));
```

Sort the lists:

```
list1.Sort();
list2.Sort();
```

Now you can easily create arrays from the lists:

```
string[][] Arr = new string[2][];
Arr[0] = list1.ToArray();
Arr[1] = list2.ToArray();
```

---

If you want to do it in the other order, i.e. first sort then split, it would be:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add(textbox1.Text);
list.Add(textbox2.Text);
list.Sort();
string[][] Arr = new string[2][];
Arr[0] = list[0].split(',');
Arr[1] = list[1].split(',');
```

Comment: I had tried this but i keep getting an error about not being able to convert from char[] to string. Please see the edit to my original question.

Comment: @HansRudel: What you have is not two lists of strings, where the strings can be sorted, you only have one list containing the two strings from the textboxes. When you convert a single string to an array, you get an array of characters. Look at the code that I added above.

Comment: Yeah, i managed to get it to work. Ive mark yours and the other 2 answers as +1 as i should have explained things a little clearer about what i meant by sort. Thanks very much for your help though.

Answer (score 3):

```
Arr[0] = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
Arr[1] = textBox2.Text.Split(',');
```

*EDIT* If you need preprocessing of the lists, you can just do it like so:

```
var array1 = textbox1.Text.Split(',').OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
var array2 = textbox2.Text.Split(',').OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
// extra processing here
string[][] Arr = new string[2][];
Arr[0] = array1;
Arr[1] = array2;
```

Comment: That uses the original data from the textboxes, not the lists that the OP has already created and sorted.

Answer (score 2):

```
string[][] Arr = new string[]{textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text} //<--or "tempString"
                    .Select(s => s.Split(','))
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Maaan! Do you think everybody will get what you specified

Comment: @Sivaraman But left side of the assigment `string[][] Arr` implies what it produces